# How to specify range key condition in BatchGetItem query in DynamoDB?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Method BatchGetItemRequest(Map requestItems) does not allow to add any Keys or Range conditions. Without range key, BatchGetItemRequest fails. How do I specify range key condition with comparison operators?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get requests ([GetItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#getItem%28com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.GetItemRequest%29)/[BatchGetItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#batchGetItem%28com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.BatchGetItemRequest%29)) doesn't support any conditions whatsoever.

When you ask to get an item, you're required to know exactly what you want (supply it's full primary key)

If you wish to have conditions (search) - you should check [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#scan%28com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScanRequest%29) (full table) or [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html#query%28com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.QueryRequest%29) (supply hash, search for ranges)